# How to print the name of many ID query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 queries one is this:

```
select nameCode
from users
where id = 3
```

When this query is executed there are many nameCode like

**9616,1234,2456,3678...etc**

Now I have this other query:

```
select description
from rights
where nameCode = 1234
```

and when I execute it, it shows

**1234 => "Rights to use car"**

How can I make a query where it takes all the nameCode and shows me all the description?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: What's your dbms

Comment: @D-Shih sql server

Comment: @D-Shih there are many values with id = 3 it can be like 20 or more. Now these values have nameCode and each nameCode has a description. All i want is after i print all the NameCode with id=3 i want to print all their descriptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to use `JOIN` to make it, `JOIN` with `users` and `rights` by `nameCode`

```
SELECT description
FROM users u
INNER JOIN rights r
ON u.nameCode = r.nameCode
WHERE u.id = 3
```

if you need to select more columns you can add columns that you expect to get.

another way you can try to use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT description
FROM rights u
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM users u 
    WHERE u.nameCode = r.nameCode AND u.id = 3 
)
```

Comment: I will try it now